# Magento 2.3.1 : Strange error

Tags: magento2.3.1, compiler

I have a strange, useless and a way funny error like Magento know how to do. When executing `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`:

> Firebear\ImportExport\Model\Import\Address
>                   Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Address\Attribute\CollectionFactory.
>   Actual type:
>   \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Address\CollectionFactory; File:
>   /var/www/MyWebSite/magento/app/code/Firebear/ImportExport/Model/Import/Address.php
>
> Total Errors Count: 1
>
> In Log.php line 92:
>                                  Error during compilation

For me this error looks like :
Magento: "I want CollectionFactory"
Firebear import export extension : "ok I give you CollectionFactory"
Magento: "nope error"
So if someone sees something else please tell me, it would be really useful for me.
PS: in case of Minus please let me know why so that I can improve my post.

Comment: pass attribute collectionFactory instead of Address CollectionFactory.

Comment: but then I should override the extension ? because in my extension file both are passed : \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Address\CollectionFactory $addressColFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Address\Attribute\CollectionFactory $attributesFactory,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to update the FireBear extension